# using foundation-3.2.2 I want to slide both image and content at a time

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using foundation-3.2.2 , but I am facing image slider problem, I used both  orbit image slider or content slider but its not helpful.

Problem is that on my site I want to slide both image and content at a time , and my html structure is below, you can chack ths `http://ipadfeatures.info/yogita/envision.com` to maximize and minimize your browser.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
        <div id="featuredContent">
            <div>
               <img src="images/illustration/spotlight1.jpg"/>
               <div class="data">
                    <h3 class="textWeight">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed"</h3>              
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>        
                <img src="images/illustration/spotlight2.jpg"/>
                <div class="data">
                    <h3 class="textWeight">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed"</h3>
                    <a href="html/corporatePrograms.html" class="topMargin">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</a>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div>        
                <img src="images/illustration/spotlight3.jpg"/>
                <div class="data">
                    <h3>""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed</h3>
                    <a href="html/cadCourses.html" class="topMargin">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, c</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Zurb has responded to this topic [on this github page](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/402).

Unfortunately variable content sliding in Foundation 3 was not what the Orbit slider was planned for, it has been updated in Foundation 4.0 to do so, but in 3 it is not supported.